# Is calling a method on a class and passing an instance manually always equivalent to calling the method on an instance?

Tags: python

I.e. given a class and an instance like this:

```
class Foo:
    def bar(self):
        ...

foo = Foo()
```

is `Foo.bar(foo)` always equivalent to `foo.bar()`, or are there corner cases where the former call can lead to unexpected results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not necessarily. The [descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/3.7/howto/descriptor.html) allows you to define what it means for an object to be accessed as an attribute.

- `Foo.bar(foo)`  is equivalent to `Foo.__dict__['bar'].__get__(None, Foo)`
- `foo.bar()` is equivalent to `type(foo).__dict__['bar'].__get__(foo, type(foo))`

There are two points of divergence. First, `type(foo)` may or may not be `Foo`, and second, depending on how `__get__` is defined, the results when `__get__` receives `foo` vs. `None` as its first argument may differ.

Comment: I should add that in the absence of inheritance, I think the definition of `function.__get__` does make the two equivalent. `bar.__get__(None, ...)` just returns `bar`, while` bar.__get__(foo,...)` returns a bound method representing `bar` already partially applied to `foo`.

Answer (score 0):

The corner case comes into play when `Foo.bar()` is decorated, e.g. in one of the two following ways:

```
class Foo:
    @classmethod
    def bar(cls, inst):
        ...

    @staticmethod
    def bar(inst):
        ...
```

In the former case, calling `Foo.bar()` automatically passes *the class `Foo`* as an argument - not an instance of the class, but the class itself. If you were to make a subclass `Bar`, then `Bar.bar()` would pass the class `Bar` as an argument. This is useful for polymorphism.

In the latter case, there are no implicit parameters being passed. You still have to call the method through its class (`Foo.bar()`) but neither the instance on which it is called (if you do that for some reason) nor the class on which it is called are passed as parameters.

---

In general, though, `Foo.bar(foo)` is equivalent to `foo.bar()` - the default behavior of methods in a class is to accept the instance on which the method is called as the first parameter of that method.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `foo.bar`, it first tries to lookup `bar` on `foo` itself. As `bar` is defined in the class `Foo` and not the instance `foo`, it will fail. Only *then* does it move on and attempts to lookup `bar` on `foo.__class__` (i.e. `Foo`), and succeeds. We can exploit this:

```
class Foo:
    def bar(self):
        ...

foo = Foo()
foo.bar = lambda: print('hello')
```

Now, `foo.bar()` and `Foo.bar(foo)` results in distinct actions, as different functions will be resolved in the two cases.